# biholomorphic function $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Exists there a biholomorphic function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$?

My idea:

Suppose, there exists a biholomorphic function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Because of $f(z)\neq 0  \ \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ there exists $\delta>0$ with $|f(z)|\geq \delta\ \forall z \in\mathbb{C}$.

Define $g\colon\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}.$ Then $g$ is holomorphic and bounded by $\frac{1}{\delta}$. Because of Liouville $g$ (and so $f$) is constant: contradiction!

Is this correct?

Edit:
$\mathbb{C}$ is simply-connected.
Suppose, $f$ is biholomorphic.
Then $f(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is simply-connected.
This is a contradiction because $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is not simply-connected.

Comment: how do you conclude there is such a $\delta$? Do you mean the extended complex plane $\Bbb{C} \cup \infty$?

Comment: @onriv I just meant the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. My conclusion: When $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is biholomorphic, there exists no $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $f(z)=0$, so there exists $\delta$:$|f(z)|\geq\delta$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio ah so my conclusion is not correct, do you have any other ideas how to proof this statement?

Comment: The existence of such an $\delta$ is still not apparent to me. No $z$ satisfying $f(z)=0$ does not mean no $|f(z)|$ being arbitrary close to $0$. Maybe your idea is OK, but you should maybe try to add more details for the existence of $\delta$. And usually, a more straightforward proof is using the topological properties that $\Bbb{C}$ is simply connected while $\Bbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$ is not. Btw your tags are not corresponding to your question, so I changed it to complex-analysis.

Comment: I found my mistake and proofed the statement by using simply connectness

Comment: You could maybe answer your own question to show the valid proof.

Comment: If this is a complex analysis course, you should attempt a proof that uses complex analysis. There is no simple way to show that the plane and the punctured plane are not homeomorphic on strictly topological grounds (how do you know the punctured plane is not simply connected? Is such a fact fair game for the course?).

Comment: For a complex analytic proof, you can compare the groups of automorphism of these two spaces (as the tag suggested before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\gamma$ be the image of the unit sphere $\partial B_1(0)$ under the proposed inverse $g: \mathbb C^\times \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ of your biholomorphic map $f : \mathbb C\longrightarrow \mathbb C^\times$. Then prove and study the consequences of the equality of integrals

$$
\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)} dw  =\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_{\partial B_1(0)}\frac {dz} z
$$

by observing that $f'/f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: (Notice that in spirit this is a proof that uses the fundamental group, as integrating loops over the form $(2\pi iz)^{-1}dz$ gives you an isomorphism $\pi_1(\mathbb C^\times)\cong \mathbb Z$.)